# Execute df | grep -w "/" not parsing output correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run the shell command `df -h | grep -w "/"` using python to watch the root partition usage and wanted to avoid `shell=True` option for security.

The code I tried as follows:

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-w', '"/"'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output=p2.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

The output I get is:

```
$ ./subprocess_df_check.py 
b''
```

Expected output is:

```
$ df -h | grep -w "/"
/dev/sdd        251G  4.9G  234G   3% /
```

Comment: I think grep may be looking for the literal pattern `"/"` including the quotes.  Try taking out the double quotes.  You don't need them anyway, since `/` is not a shell special character.

Comment: Excellent, that was the issue. But the output now printed as `(b'/dev/sdd        251G  4.9G  234G   3% /\n', None)`. How do you remove those additional "b" "\n", "None" stuff from the output?.

Comment: `'grep', '-w', '/'` -- the double quotes are for the shell, not for `df`. When you have no shell, you need no shell syntax.

Comment: @JohnW, if you still have the parenthesis and a `None`, that means your real code didn't have the `[0]`, so you were printing a `(stdout, stderr)` tuple instead of just the stdout. Make your code match what you showed in the question and you won't have that problem. (As for `b''`, we have hundreds of already-answered questions about that in the knowledgebase: It means you have a bytestring instead of a Unicode string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured out the whole thing.

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-w', '/'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output=p2.communicate()[0].split()[4]
print("Root partition is of", output.decode(), "usage now")
```

- Removed unnecessary double quotes, changed from `subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-w', '"/"']` to `subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-w', '/']`. The double quotes are for the shell, not for df. When you have no shell, you need no shell syntax.
- On `output=p2.communicate()[0].split()[4]`, the `[0]` picks only stdout, not the stderr, which is `None` if no error. Then `split()[4]` cuts the 4th column which is disk usage percent value from shell `df` command.
- `output.decode()`, the `decode()` is to decode the encoded bytes string format and avoid outputting character `b` in front of the result. Refer [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-b-in-front-of-string/)

So the output of the script is:

```
$ ./subprocess_df_check.py
Root partition is of 3% usage now
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use subprocess with `df` and / or `grep`. If you already use python, you can use the `statvfs` function call like:

```
import os
import time

path = "/"

while True:
    info = os.statvfs(path)
    print("Block size [%d]  Free blocks [%d]  Free inodes [%d]"
          % (info.f_bsize, info.f_bfree, info.f_ffree))
    time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is the unnecessary quotes being added.

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-w', '"/"'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

is **not** equivalent to the shell command `grep -w "/"`. Instead, it's equivalent to the shell command `grep -w '"/"'`, (or `grep -w \"/\"`, or any other means of writing an argument vector that passes literal double-quote characters on the last non-NUL element of `grep`'s argument vector) and wrong for the same reasons.

Use `'/'`, not `'"/"'`.

Answer (score 1):

Running `grep` in a separate subprocess is certainly unnecessary. If you are using Python, you already have an excellent tool for looking for substrings within strings.

```
df = subprocess.run(['df', '-h'],
    capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
for line in df.stdout.split('\n')[1:]:
    if '/' in line:
        print(line)
```

Notice also how you basically always want to prefer `subprocess.run` over `Popen` when you can, and how you want `text=True` to get text rather than `bytes`. Usually you also want `check=True` to ensure that the subprocess completed successfully.

Comment: You're most welcome. For (much) more on this topic, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538